# mysql: select max(score) doesn't return the relevant row data

Tags: mysql, max

if i have for example a scores table:

```
    user game score timestamp
    1    50   50    date
    2    60   40    date
    3    70   25    date
    4    80   18    date
```

and i run the query:

```
select user, game, max(score), timestamp from scores
```

i will receive the maximum score number that is 20, but the rest of the columns that are returned are not from that same row.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are using `MAX`, which is an aggregate function. Aggregate functions have the effect of treating multiple rows in the table as a group. If you don't do anything special, all rows in the entire table will be used as one big group, and when an aggregrate function like `MAX` is there, all these rows will be condensed into just one aggregate row. That condensing effect would have occurred also for other aggregate functions like `MIN`, `SUM`, `GROUP_CONCAT` and friends (see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html). You can also apply specific groupings using the `GROUP BY` construct, but if you don't the occurrence of the aggregate function will just bunch up all rows into one row (but this bunching-up occurs after applying the `WHERE` condition, so only the filtered rows are aggregated)

Now, because of this condensing or 'reducing' effect of aggregate functions, there as to be some way to make one value out of many values. For `MAX`, that way is to list only the maximum value found for all instances of the expression you passed as argument to `MAX`. But your other columns do not have such an aggregate function.  For most database products, the occurrence of both unaggregated as well as aggregated columns in the `SELECT` list would be an error. But MySQL behaves wrongly/differently and returns just one of the available values for each non-aggregated expression listed in the `SELECT` bit. Which value is up to mysql - you can't rely on any particular algorithm.

In many cases, people want to do something with "whatever row that has the maximum value", in other words, find the row that has as value the maximum value, but use the other columns from that row unaggregated. The solution provided by middaparka does that, and there are otherways to achieve that too (google for MySQL group-wise maximum). For more general information about aggregate functions and the related `GROUP BY` clause, you could take a look at -shameless selfplug- my article here: http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2007/05/debunking-group-by-myths.html

Comment: awesome answer! exactly that information i needed to understand how things work. thanks

Comment: My pleasure ufk :) glad it's useful for you.

Answer (score 11):

As you're not using a GROUP clause, the max function is returning the maximum value from across the table. As such, if you want to return the matching data for the highest score, you'd need to:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query works as designed: It lists users, and the highest overall score.

To get the user with the highest score, you could use

```
select user, game, score, timestamp from scores ORDER by score DESC limit 1
```

Comment: Well, it lists the max score, but I don't feel the other columns lists users. rather, for each column some value is picked - you can't rely on them being from the same original row.