# Select rows not pointed by any other row on self referencing table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have a self referencing table and I'm having trouble finding rows that don't have any other rows pointing to it - or, **in other words**, getting the ones that aren't parents to any other, meaning, of course, they don't have children.

This is my table with sample data:

```
+----+------+--------+
| id | name | cat_id |
+----+------+--------+
|  1 | C1   |        |
|  2 | C2   |        |
|  3 | C3   |      1 |
|  4 | C4   |      2 |
|  5 | C5   |      2 |
|  6 | C6   |      5 |
+----+------+--------+
```

Here, `cat_id` is the parent. This is a 'representation':

`.
├── C1
|   └── C3
└── C2
    ├── C4
    └── C5
        └── C6`

As seen, categories can have sub-categories indefinitely and they are defined by pointing to `cat_id`. If it's a 'main' category, it just doesn't point to anything. I can get all categories that **don't** have a 'parent' by selecting `NULL` in `cat_id`, but how do I select categories that don't have 'children'?

I tried:

```
SELECT
    c1.id, c1.name, c1.cat_id
FROM
    cat c1
INNER JOIN
    cat c2
ON
    c1.id != c2.cat_id
```

But this not only returns duplicated rows, but also includes categories that have children. The **expected results** are in bold in the representation. You can run tests in [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/23ac88/1).

How can I accomplish this? Is it achievable without recursion?

Comment: I added the tags to be more specific, but I'd say it's pretty much an SQL-related question.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23751672/sql-query-how-to-extract-last-child-of-a-table

Comment: This type of relationship is usually evaluated with recursion.  Is there a particular reason you are trying to avoid recursion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably what you were aiming for in your initial query:

```
select a.*
from cat a left outer join
   cat b on a.id = b.cat_id
where b.cat_id is null
```

Comment: Ok, it just clicked.. ::::: get everything from the table (`left`) -> bring the ones that have a parent (`join/on`), the ones that don't have children won't merge, causing them to not have a reference -> remove null references (`where`)..  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

One way to find nodes without children is to use `not exists` to only select rows that are not referenced as parents in the `cat_id` column:

```
select id from cat c1
where not exists (
    select 1 from cat c2 where c2.cat_id = c1.id
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select * from cat
where id not in (
    select distinct cat_id 
    from cat
    where cat_id is not null)
```

Finding rows that don't have any other rows pointing to it, means finding rows which `'id'` is not in any row of `'cat_id'` column.