# Select last record in the table

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

How to select last record (that is having `MAX(id)`) from the table?
Next statement works OK, but selects the first record:

```
$statistics = SystemStatisticsHistory::findOne(1);
```

Answer (score 30):

To get the model with max `id` you can apply reverse order and limit to one.

```
SystemStatisticsHistory::find()->orderBy(['id' => SORT_DESC])->one();
```

Another option is to use subselect with `max` like so:

```
SystemStatisticsHistory::find()
    ->where(['id' => SystemStatisticsHistory::find()->max('id')])
    ->one();
```

There are some nuances using last option, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604893/sql-select-row-from-table-where-id-maxid).

You can check the documentation for `max()` [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html#max%28%29-detail).

I personally prefer using first variation.

To get the first record, just change the order direction to `SORT_ASC` in first query and `max()` to `min()` in second query.

**P.S.** Hardcoded `id` is a bad practice.

Comment: Glad to help. Mark the answer as accepted in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Optimised one

```
SystemStatisticsHistory::find()->select(['id'=>'MAX(`id`)'])->one()->id;
```

OR if you want increase by number

```
SystemStatisticsHistory::find()->select(['id'=>'( MAX(`id`)+ 1) '])->one()->id;
```