# How can I set id_supply to the last entry/id in suply

Tags: mysql, sql, max

I've used [This Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604893/sql-select-row-from-table-where-id-maxid) for my query:

```
UPDATE breads
SET id_supply = (SELECT max(id) FROM supply)
WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM breads)
```

I have added a new record into supply. Now I want my last bread to have the id_supply of the last supply.id

```
#1093 - Table 'breads' is specified twice, 
both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data
```

Comment: Does your query work or not?

Comment: This seems correct to me. Are you getting an error? What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, you cannot refer to the table being updated subsequently in the query (well, without a little hack).

Instead, use `order by` and `limit`:

```
UPDATE breads b
    SET b.id_supply = (SELECT max(s.id) FROM supply s)
    ORDER BY b.id DESC
    LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: @Halfacht . . . If that is the case, then the `id_supply` of the "last" row is already set to the maximum supply id.

Answer (score 0):

If the answer given by @Gordon is not working, then I guess you should try a little hack he's talking about in his answer.

Although, Gordon's query works fine with my Test data, but if it's not working for you then try the following query:

```
UPDATE breads
SET id_supply = (SELECT max(id) FROM supply)
WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(br.id) FROM (select *from breads) br);
```

Click here for the [Demo](http://rextester.com/DKK55163)

Hope it helps!

**Note:** If this query won't work too, then you should add the Schema and 
          Sample data into your question.