# How to add every last record on the database? E.g. 1 += 1

Tags: php, mysql, database

So, Im fetching the last record on the table "energy"

```
function find_all_energy() {
    global $db;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM energy ORDER BY energyID DESC";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    $energy = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    mysqli_free_result($result);

    return $energy;
}
```

The last record returns "1000", but what if there are new inserted record(s) like "2000", I want to return it as "3000" because of ( += ) and new inserted record(s) again like "5000" then it will fetch it as "8000" and so on. Thank you!

Comment: If you need the sum of a column for all rows then simply use `SUM(columnName)`. If that's not the case add some data and the expected output.

Comment: I need to add the data within the date e.g. only in March 16, 2018 data will be += from the current data. Then if it becomes march 17, then it will add the data within its date

Comment: Please provide a sample of your data and the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

What you what is the last line of your table ?
I would suggest to do it with a MAX(id) on a WHERE requirement, like it is suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604893/sql-select-row-from-table-where-id-maxid) :

```
SELECT row 
FROM table 
WHERE id=(
    SELECT max(id) FROM table
    )
```