# $sel = $mysqli->query("SELECT max(number) AS max_number, id FROM table ")

Tags: php

i have table as following

```
Id - Number - value
1  - 1000   - 20
2  - 2000   - 30
3  - 3000   - 35
```

While I tried with

```
$sel = $mysqli->query("SELECT max(number) AS max_number, id FROM table ");
$sel_row = $sel->fetch_object();
$id = $sel_row->id;
```

I get `$id = 1`, but I am looking for `$id = 3`;

Comment: Your query means: "select maximum `number` column and some random `id` column". So the result is pretty expected.

Comment: Dup of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081211/mysql-select-maxscore-doesnt-return-the-relevant-row-data-how-to-solve-the-i and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604893/sql-select-row-from-table-where-id-maxid

Comment: You can rework your query as: `SELECT number, id FROM table ORDER BY number DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: use `SELECT number AS max_number, id FROM table ORDER BY number DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I select an entire row which has the largest ID in the table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604893/how-do-i-select-an-entire-row-which-has-the-largest-id-in-the-table)